# Getting non ref value from iter method

Tags: rust, reference

```
let shoes = vec![
    Shoe {
        size: 10,
        style: String::from("sneaker"),
    },
    Shoe {
        size: 13,
        style: String::from("sandal"),
    },
    Shoe {
        size: 10,
        style: String::from("boot"),
    },
];

let shoe_size = 10;
let filtered_shoes: Vec<&Shoe> = shoes.iter().filter(|s| s.size == shoe_size).collect();
let shoe_0: &Shoe = shoes.get(0).unwrap();
println!("address vec shoe {:p}", shoes);
println!("address filtered shoe {:p}", filtered_shoes);
println!("{:?}", filtered_shoes);
println!("{:?}", shoe_0);
```

Given collect fn following the filter operation, why is the return type `Vec<&Shoe>` instead of `Vec<Shoe>`.
Please note that `into_iter` is not a possibility here.

In other languages like javascript, filter would copy from the original and would return new vector. Printing the address of those 2 vectors shows two different addresses.

The other was part how to make `shoe_0` have the type of `Shoe` instead of `&Shoe`?

Comment: *"In other languages like javascript, filter would copy"* - JavaScript and many other languages are GC'd and therefore have shared ownership by default (for objects, primitives copy), they not have references like Rust does. In encourage you to read in the Rust Book about [understanding ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html). In essence, to have two `Shoe`s where there used to be only one there must be a copy or clone step, and Rust makes this explicit.

Comment: @kmdreko, so ```println!("{:p} {:p}", filtered_shoes.get(0).unwrap(), shoes.get(0).unwrap());``` these addresses are different,  but there was no explicit clone.

Comment: `filtered_shoes.get(0).unwrap()` would get a `&&Shoe`, so you're printing the address of the *reference*, not the address of the `Shoe` it ultimately points to.

Comment: got it, this shows same value, so both are pointing to shoes[0]
`println!("{:p} {:p}", (*filtered_shoes.get(0).unwrap()), shoes.get(0).unwrap());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the selling points of Rust, it doesn't hide creating copies or otherwise managing the memory form you like JavaScript, a garbage collected language would. Instead, you have to explicitly instruct it to do so. For that you need a way to convert references to a shoe (`&Shoe`) into owned `Shoe`s, the most common being deriving `Clone` for `Shoe` and cloning the shoes:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Shoe { /* … */ }
```

then you can use the iterator adapter `.cloned()` to convert an `Iterator<Item = &Shoe>` into an `Iterator<Item = Shoe>`

```rust
let filtered_shoes: Vec<Shoe> = shoes.iter().cloned().filter(|s| s.size == shoe_size).collect();
```

and similarly you can `.clone()` a `&Shoe` to turn it into a `Shoe`:

```rust
let shoe_0: Shoe = shoes.get(0).unwrap().clone();
```